# Схема БД для учета проведенных конференций

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Проектирую бд для системы учета проведения НИРС в ВУЗах.

У меня есть таблица `Приказы`, в которой должны быть люди, которые удтверждают приказ (1 или несколько человек), люди, которые готовят приказ (таблица `Подтверждающие`), и, если я захочу их всех добавить в таблицу `Приказ`, то будет происходить избыточность данных, т.е. будут повторятся.

К примеру у меня есть 1 человек, который создает приказ (Подтверждающий) и 2 человека которые утверждают (Удтверждающие), тогда в таблице `Приказы` будет 2 записи, в которых будут повторяться поля `Тема приказа`, `Номер приказа`, `Дата приказа`, `Код подтверждения`, и будут отличаться в 2 записях только поле `Код утдверждения`.

Как можно перестроить схему, чтобы избавиться от этого изьяна, или есть возможность хранить в поле таблицы массив данных(что врядли)?

[image: иллюстрирующая схема]

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что не все таблицы (а их тут **21** штука) относятся к вопросу. Такая схема прямо-таки пугает.

Comment: И поправьте потом у себя - таблица должна называться `Утверждающие`, а поле в ней - `IdУтверждающего`.

Comment: не понятен вопрос. выделите элементы, относящиеся к вопросу

Comment: для затравки можете посмотреть здесь http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/06/yii.html там уже правда готовое решение на yii. но в общем можно использовать многие-ко многим и указывать ссылку на сводную таблицу

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз это уже сделал)

Answer (score 3):

> будет происходить избыточность данных

да, при описанной схеме работы факт и момент подписания (а в идеале — и отзыва) подписи следует фиксировать в отдельной таблице, связанной с таблицей приказов и таблицей(-ами) полномочий.

но если все приказы соответствуют шаблону «три подписи», то, вероятно, проще будет добавить в таблицу приказов три соответствующих поля, содержащих либо `null`, либо `id` подписавшего/утвердившего.

---

а в принципе, вопросы «оцифровывания» документооборота вообще, и фиксации подписаний-утверждений-согласований-отклонений в частности — тема достаточно обширная. в наиболее полном варианте, например, обязательно следует учитывать тот факт, что полномочия подписания предоставляются лишь на время.

т.е. начинать надо с грамотной постановки задачи, в которой чётко определить, насколько «оцифрованный» документооборот будет упрощён относительно реального.